# NHibernate How to add extensions manually?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I would like to use [this method](http://adrianphinney.com/post/18900251364/nhibernate-raw-sql-and-dynamic-result-sets) to get data dynamically from my database. As explained in that topic, I should add an extension to my nhibernate config.

Could someone say, please, how to add that extension ?

Thanks in advance.

```
public static class NhTransformers
{
    public static readonly IResultTransformer ExpandoObject;

    static NhTransformers()
    {
        ExpandoObject = new ExpandoObjectResultSetTransformer();
    }

    private class ExpandoObjectResultSetTransformer : IResultTransformer
    {
        public IList TransformList(IList collection)
        {
            return collection;
        }

        public object TransformTuple(object[] tuple, string[] aliases)
        {
            var expando = new ExpandoObject();
            var dictionary = (IDictionary<string, object>)expando;
            for (int i = 0; i < tuple.Length; i++)
            {
                string alias = aliases[i];
                if (alias != null)
                {
                    dictionary[alias] = tuple[i];
                }
            }
            return expando;
        }
    }
}

public static class NHibernateExtensions
{
    public static IList<dynamic> DynamicList(this IQuery query)
    {
        return query.SetResultTransformer(NhTransformers.ExpandoObject)
                .List<dynamic>();
    }
}

-----------------------------------
USE CASE
-----------------------------------

var results = this.session.CreateSQLQuery("select Id, Title, Body from [Posts]")
              .DynamicList(); // Secret sauce!
// results are now dynamic!
Console.WriteLine(results[0].Id);
Console.WriteLine(results[0].Name);
// rock on!
```

Comment: What you mean by "manually", i have not tried but should work.

Comment: I mean how can I use/add this method in my existing nhibernate environment.

Comment: You dont need it, just call it (add usings) and must work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I only created NhTransformers class and did like this;

```
var query1 = " select * from mySQLView";

var result1 = this.session.CreateSQLQuery(query1).SetResultTransformer(NhTransformers.ExpandoObject)
                .List<dynamic>();

foreach (var obj in result1)
{
   // some stuff...
}
```